# Change VBA Editor Color Scheme to something darker

Tags: vba

Is there a way to change the color scheme in the VBA editor that comes with Microsoft Office?  I have been spending several hours lately working with VBA in Excel, and the bright white background is making my eyes sad.  I know I can change the settings manually in the menu `Tools-->Editor Options` on the tab `Editor Format`, but I was hoping there was something like a themes plugin.  I prefer a light-on-dark theme like Obsidian.

Is there a plugin for the VBA editor to change the color scheme?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @PowerUser.  I did not realize that the VBA editor gets its default colors from the registry.

Comment: No problem. I was actually curious about it myself since I like black backgrounds. I googled it and, surprise, I found myself looking at another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I went ahead and manually changed my background to grey; the frustrating part is that I had to change the background for each element (e.g. identifiers, keywords, comments, etc.) to grey so nothing had awkward, white highlighting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use custom colours in the Microsoft VBA editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/313408/how-can-i-use-custom-colours-in-the-microsoft-vba-editor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odd, when the question migrated over from SO, my first comment with the link was deleted.  Here it is again:

[How can I use custom colours in the Microsoft VBA editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/313408/how-can-i-use-custom-colours-in-the-microsoft-vba-editor)

Since you're manually changing everything, my only other suggestion is to make sure you don't accidentally make some highlighting color invisible against your new background.

Answer (score 4):

Five years after the question, but worth checking... You wrote:

> the bright white background is making my eyes sad

### Don't address only the VBA editor, address the entire Windows session at once.

Use [NegativeScreen](https://zerowidthjoiner.net/negativescreen) open-source freeware to temporarily invert your entire Windows color scheme by transforming its colors. This will solve white background problem in all Windows apps at once.

- Using a hotkey, you can enable/disable color transformation whenever you need it.
- You can create your own color transformations to further aid your eyes - for example to decrease contrast. (Such a matrix is in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1059140/287473).)

This solution is almost 100% reliable, because it uses functionality of built-in Magnifier accessibility tool which is implemented directly by the Microsoft so it has no quirks or strange side effects (what I can confirm from my few years' experience with its daily use).