# How to reduce my desktop screen brightness

Tags: display, brightness

My desktop machine is a Windows 7 32-bit. My problem is that when I read a PDF, the brightness of screen bothers me and I want to reduce it. My monitor is a Samsung LCD and only has a button. When I press it one time it turn the screen on/off and when I press and hold it, it just adjusts the wallpaper.

Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: ...it adjusts the wall paper? Really? Hmm.... Any way, just because your screen doesn't have the brightness button doesn't mean it's `definitely` not controllable; I suggest you search for the monitor model and see if there is any software for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how a desktop screen could adjust the Windows wallpaper, but if you really can't adjust the brightness of your screen, you could check out

- [Flux.io](http://justgetflux.com/)
- [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)

Both programs change the hue and gamma of your OS color profile to ease your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [NegativeScreen](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2415/1466) which gives you full control on all color components (red, green, blue). You can reach fantastic eye-relieving reults just by inverting the colors.

Of course you CAN also reduce the brightness (what you were asking) or [contrast of the display](https://superuser.com/a/1059140/287473) just by adjusting transformation matrixes.

If you are asking because of sort of eye problems, check [e-ink displays](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2415/1466). They emit no light at all, have no flicker, they feel as reading the book.