# Sepia Filter On windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, display, laptop-display, color-theme

When reading Books on android (using almost any application) I can activate sepia mode, which,  is easier on the eyes. I wanted the same thing on windows so I started digging but I could not find anything.
[Also I'm on a laptop so it isn't easy(or possible) to directly change the display settings as would be on a separate monitor]

Is there any software which can turn the display output to sepia ?
Or just a book reader(with sepia or night mode) ? Even an extension for chrome would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sepia mode is definitely available for Windows. Get [NegativeScreen](http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/) and find **Negative Sepia** mode out-of-the-box.

To get **standard sepia** mode, add this transformation matrix into configuration file:

```
Sepia=win+shift+alt+F7
{ 0.393, 0.349, 0.272, 0.000, 0.000 }
{ 0.769, 0.686, 0.534, 0.000, 0.000 }
{ 0.189, 0.168, 0.131, 0.000, 0.000 }
{ 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000, 0.000 }
{ 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000 }
```

You can find nice red, green, amber, black&white modes, too.  (For amber and green, search discussion on download page.)

I recommend inverted colors for reading, they are better than sepia mode. Also I recommend [reducing screen contrast](https://superuser.com/a/1059140/287473), it helps, too, even more than other mentioned things.

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue due to the time of day you are reading? Or the overall brightness/contrast of the screen?

You could use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to have your screen automatically change warmth over the course of the day, making it much easier on your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

There are as such no applications that I know which can have theme like "Sepia" for entire Windows OS. But there is one for Chrome which I use.
Try [High contrast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en) app for Chrome. It has Grey, Inverted colors, Yellow on black options - meant to be easy on the eyes.
For PDF's i invert colors and read them from Adobe reader. Press 'Ctrl+K`. This will bring up the **Preferences** dialog and Select *Accessibility*. There you have the choice to invert colours.