# Notepad++ Zenburn that behaves well using Compare?

Tags: notepad++

The Zenburn theme in Notepad++ is great, except for one little thing. If you do a side-by-side file compare using the Compare plugin, the result is pretty much illegible, so you have to switch to the Default theme.

Which is not a major problem, but still.

Is there any remedy for this, other than creating a derivative of Zenburn?

**Edit** to illustrate,

Zenburn compare view:
[image: not so legible]

Default compare view:
[image: OK, but not Zenburn]

Comment: Maybe you could add a screenshot of how "the result is pretty much illegible"...

Comment: @miroxlav done.

Answer (score 0):

In menu **Plugins** > **Compare** > **Settings...** try reducing **Highlight Transparency** from `100` to `50`. Semi-transparent colors may then blend better with any theme you choose.

---

Another way can be to create [ZenBurn-like effect for the entire Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1059140/287473). That way you can keep your N++ in default theme (keeping all the necessary contrasts) and still have grey-dominated screen, not only in N++, but in all apps. In the linked answer, there is a definition of contrast-lowering matrix working similarily to Zenburn. Maybe you can add it into the config and try it out or tweak it further to your needs. Remember that you can switch the color filter on and off anytime with a single key (...any unused keys like "Calculator" on your keyboard?) so it can be more convenient than switching themes in N++.